# MS Excel: Return value of closing balance of LAST MONTH and THIS MONTH for each accounts

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find the formula that would return the closing balance of the last month (in one column)
and the current month balance up to date (if there is a transaction during the month, it would update the account closing balance even though the month is not over). Let me know if it's not clear and thanks in advance for your feedback/suggestions :)!

Here's a print screen to have a better idea:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02PXG.png)

Comment: Could you please post samples in form of text in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you. Images and links are NOT encouraged on SO.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13!I finally was able to solve my issue but thanks for taking the time to try to help me :)! But do you know why images are not encouraged (it would make the process a little efficient than just texting no)?? I'm new here so I don't know exactly how it works neither the rules/recommendations.